# What is the function of each word in "schon mal"?

Tags: expression

What is the function of "schon" and of "mal"?

Comment: In what way did a dictionary not help you?

Comment: Is the interesting way these two words ("already", "x times") combine to give their generally accepted meaning not beyond the scope of most dictionaries?